# Cannot index into a null array on assignment?

Tags: powershell

all.

About to lose it - This was working hours ago.

So when I run this I get

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:3 char:15
+ $backlog[0]=$(Get-DFSRBacklog -sourcecomputername:ts-fileshares2 -destinationcom ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Issue being, when I search here and elsewhere, I find people making issues assigning a null array TO a variable. Not assigning to the array.

Below is most of the code (I am running this against multiple fileshares, too lazy to change server names in six lines. Typically backlog[] contains 6 sets of replies.

```
clear-host
$backlog[0]=$(Get-DFSRBacklog -sourcecomputername:a -destinationcomputername:b -Verbose) 4>&1

#$collection is one array result. This will be easier to split out into by-server later.
[int]$total = 0
foreach ($collection in $backlog)
{
    $collection | ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_.getType().FullName.equals("System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord"))
        {
            #$_ | Get-Member
            #Write-Host $_.Message
            if ($_.Message -like "*has a backlog*")
            {
                #testing write-host $_.Message.split(" ")[12]
                $total += [convert]::ToInt32($_.Message.split(" ")[12],10)
            }
        }
    }
}
#testing Write-Host $total
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TOTALFILESHAREBACKLOG",$total, "Machine")
#testing Write-Host $env:TOTALFILESHAREBACKLOG
```

As I said, this was working hours ago. Not sure if I have some weird variable stuck, but this is on out prod server (no way to get DFSR backlog from a non-prod server) so I don't want to reboot the entire server.

This is a signed powershell script that is running on a schedule (zabbix pulls the env variable later for reporting) but that shouldn't affect it. The only thing that I changed between this working and not working was moving where this file was saved.

The Powershell Get-DFSRBacklog does always return a value or print an error, so that's not it.

Even doing $backlog[0] = 1 throws an error.

P.P.S.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                 
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                               
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                       
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                                                        
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: "*Typically backlog[] contains 6 sets of replies.*" - and yet in this case, it is `$null`.  So where is `$backlog` being defined?

Comment: It is defined as it is created and assigned, no? This is the entirety of the script (aside from having five other sets of responses put into backlog)

Comment: If that is the entire script then I'm going with "it never worked" because `$x[0] = 1` hasn't ever been a valid way to define a variable from scratch. It would have to be `$backlog=$(Get-DFSRBacklog -sourcecomputername:a -destinationcomputername:b -Verbose) 4>&1` with no `[]` for the first definition. Once it is an array, then you can `[0]` it.

Comment: I think I'm having a mandela moment, then. Perhaps it didn't work but I swear it did. I even have records in my Zabbix box from it updating the variable. Perhaps I had $backlog created from a previous incarnation (I wrote all of this in one sitting) and it still was initialized. At any rate, just after I posted this I tried adding $backlog=0,0,0,0,0,0 at the top and it resolved the issue. I'll post it as an answer once I test. I could have sworn you didn't have to initialize an array before using it in Powershell.

Comment: Do you want an array of `backlog`s or just 1 backlog that contains an array of items?

Comment: It seems to me that this question is very specific tou your code and off topic, because it should never have worked the way you posted it.

Comment: "*I could have sworn you didn't have to initialize an array before using it in Powershell.*" - arrays in .Net are mutable but they are fixed length. That precludes using one before initializing it because you can't have an array to use, until after you've done something to set its length while creating it. You don't have to declare `[array]$x` first or go through and set all the content to 0, but you do have to create an array and specify a length (implicitly or explicitly) before you have an array to use at all, even if it's just assigning the result of a cmdlet or loop to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I am a dumbass.

You need to initialize variables before you can treat them as an array, even for assignment. The fix was to add $backlog=0,0,0,0,0,0 at the top of the $backlog[x] assignments.